# How to print duplicated items of a list as numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

#### Desired output 1:

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
my_list = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'van', 'car', 'truck', 'van']
```

I have three cars, two vans and two trucks. Is there a way to print the output of the items of the list like this:

```
3 cars
2 trucks
2 vans
```

#### Desired output 2:

And is there another method to remove the number of cars the user says like:

```
How many cars do you want to remove?: 2
1 car
2 trucks
2 vans
```

These are my questions. How can I do this in Python using the least amount of code?

> I agree there is a duplicate of this question but those don't explain how I can delete the items from my list upon user input.

Comment: Use a dictionary to store occurrences of each vehicle and a for loop iterating on your list to increment these occurrences.

Comment: how can I do it? @qouify

Comment: Partial duplicate: [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) Once you have a `Counter`, you can simply subtract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Question 1:

You can use Counter to achieve this:

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'van', 'car', 'truck', 'van']
count_dict = Counter(my_list)  # Return a dictionary

for key, value in count_dict.items():
    print(value, key)
```

#### Output:

```sh
3 car
2 truck
2 van
```

## Question 2:

You can pass the remove function in a loop:

```py
number_of_occurances = 1
string_to_remove = 'car'

for number in range(number_of_occurances):
    my_list.remove(string_to_remove)
    
print(my_list)
```

#### Output:

```sh
['car', 'truck', 'van', 'car', 'truck', 'van']
```

Comment: Note that `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, not dict per se.

Answer (score 2):

**Desired output 1:**

the list method, a simple way to look into it is the `.count()`

try it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp)
i.e

```py
cars-count = my_list.count("car")
```

**Desired output 2:**

Do you want the list updated when you run the remove items? or just the values?

i.e when you run `How many cars do you want to remove?: 1`, the list will look like this

```
my_list = ['car', 'truck', 'van', 'car', 'truck', 'van']
```

Comment: Yes, I do want the list updated. @twoscoops

Comment: `cars-count` is an invalid variable name

Comment: For part 2, this does not answer the question. Once you have enough [reputation](/help/reputation), you'll be able to leave comments on posts to ask for clarification. BTW, welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and check out [answer] if you want more tips.